# ui router resolve depends on other resolve

Tags: angularjs

I got this resolve in my state

first I get the `test` into a variable, and then I want to get the `test2` variable, but in order to get `test2` I have to wait for `test` again.

Is there a cleverer way of doing this?

Thank you

```
resolve: {
        one: function (test) {
            return test.gettest().$promise.then(data => {
                return data;
            });
        },
        two: function (test, test2, $stateParams) {
            return test.gettest().$promise.then(test=> {

                return test2.gettest2(test.id, $stateParams.id).$promise.then(data => {
                    return data;
                });

            });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you inject the first resolve variable (`one`) into the second resolve statement, angular ui router is smart enough to realize that it will not run the second resolve statement until the first one has completed. So what you would do looks something like below:

```
resolve: {
    one: function (test) {
        return test.gettest().$promise.then(data => {
            return data;
        });
    },
    two: function (one, test2, $stateParams) {
        //one is equal to the result of test.gettest()
        return test2.gettest2(one.id, $stateParams.id).$promise.then(data => {
                return data;
            });

        });
    }
},
```